# sql from clause tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query and in the from clause there is a left join with ga and following other tables.

should we use left join keyword for all other tables after ga table or we can use as it is in the query. Is there any performance issues with this query?

query:

```
from
        a@db_link st left join (Select a,b,c,d
 from b@db_link where id = 'AD' and num = 4) ga 
                                                on st.compensationdate = ga.compensationdate
                                                and st.salestransactionseq = ga.salestransactionseq    ,
        b@db_link ta,
        c@db_link cr,
        d@db_link crd_typ,
        e@db_link evt_typ,
        f@db_link disputes
        where st.salestransactionseq = ta.salestransactionseq
        and st.id = 'AD'
```

This is the query plan:

Plan hash value: 3767304471

---

```
| Id  | Operation                                           | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop | Inst   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT REMOTE                             |                             |     1 |   661 |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                                       |                             |     1 |   661 |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                                      |                             |     1 |   661 |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                                     |                             |     1 |   612 |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                                    |                             |     1 |   564 |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                                      |                             |     1 |   549 |   342   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                                  |                             |     1 |   503 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                                 |                             |     1 |   503 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                                |                             |     1 |   450 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                               |                             |     1 |   407 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |
|  10 |           PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                    |                             |     1 |   217 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1357 |  1357 |        |
|* 11 |            TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| CS_SALESTRANSACTION         |     1 |   217 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1357 |  1357 | PRD121 |
|* 12 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | CS_SALESTRANSACTION_PK      |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1357 |  1357 | PRD121 |
|  13 |           PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                    |                             |     1 |   190 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1356 |  1356 |        |
|  14 |            TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| CS_TRANSACTIONASSIGNMENT    |     1 |   190 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1356 |  1356 | PRD121 |
|* 15 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | CS_TRANSACTIONASSIGNMENT_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1356 |  1356 | PRD121 |
|* 16 |          TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | CS_GASALESTRANSACTION       |     1 |    43 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID | PRD121 |
|* 17 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | GASALESTRANSACTION_IDX      |     3 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       | PRD121 |
|  18 |         PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                      |                             |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |     8 |     8 |        |
|  19 |          PARTITION LIST ALL                         |                             |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |   268 |        |
|* 20 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | OD_CREDIT_UTVALUE           |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  1347 |  1614 | PRD121 |
|* 21 |        TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID            | CS_CREDIT                   |     1 |    53 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 | PRD121 |
|  22 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                             | ADTV_FRS_DISPUTES           | 27011 |  1213K|   341   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       | PRD121 |
|* 23 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                    | ADTV_FRS_CONTROL            |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       | PRD121 |
|* 24 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | ADTV_FRS_CONTROL_PK         |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       | PRD121 |
|  25 |     PARTITION LIST SINGLE                           |                             |     1 |    48 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |        |
|* 26 |      TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID              | CS_EVENTTYPE                |     1 |    48 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 | PRD121 |
|* 27 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | CS_EVENTTYPE_PK             |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 | PRD121 |
|  28 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE                            |                             |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |        |
|* 29 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                               | CS_CREDITTYPE_PK            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 | PRD121 |
|* 30 |   TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID                 | CS_CREDITTYPE               |     1 |    49 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 | PRD121 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("GENERICATTRIBUTE13"="A1"."ACTIVITY_ID" AND "LINENUMBER"="A1"."ITEM_ID")
  11 - filter("SUBLINENUMBER"<>2)
  12 - access("TENANTID"='ADTV' AND "PROCESSINGUNITSEQ"=3.82805968326498E16)
  15 - access("TENANTID"='ADTV' AND "PROCESSINGUNITSEQ"=3.82805968326498E16 AND "COMPENSATIONDATE"="COMPENSATIONDATE" AND 
              "SALESTRANSACTIONSEQ"="SALESTRANSACTIONSEQ")
  16 - filter("COMPENSATIONDATE"="COMPENSATIONDATE" AND "PAGENUMBER"=4)
  17 - access("SALESTRANSACTIONSEQ"="SALESTRANSACTIONSEQ" AND "TENANTID"='ADTV')
  20 - access("TENANTID"='ADTV' AND "PROCESSINGUNITSEQ"=3.82805968326498E16)
  21 - filter("SALESTRANSACTIONSEQ"="SALESTRANSACTIONSEQ" AND "SALESORDERSEQ"="SALESORDERSEQ")
  23 - filter(UPPER("A8"."STATUS")='NEW')
  24 - access("A1"."CASE_NO"="A8"."CASE_NO")
  26 - filter("EVENTTYPEID"='PROTECTIONPLAN CHARGEBACK' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='PROTECTIONPLAN CHARGEBACK-FRS' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='PROTECTIONPLAN 
              INCENTIVE' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='PROTECTIONPLAN INCENTIVE-FRS' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='PROTECTIONPLAN KICKER' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='PROTECTIONPLAN KICKER-FRS' OR 
              "EVENTTYPEID"='UNIVERSAL BILLER' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='UNIVERSAL BILLER-FRS' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='WORK ORDER' OR "EVENTTYPEID"='WORK ORDER-FRS')
  27 - access("TENANTID"='ADTV' AND "EVENTTYPESEQ"="DATATYPESEQ" AND "REMOVEDATE"=TO_DATE(' 2200-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  29 - access("TENANTID"='ADTV' AND "CREDITTYPESEQ"="DATATYPESEQ" AND "REMOVEDATE"=TO_DATE(' 2200-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  30 - filter("CREDITTYPEID"="A1"."CREDIT_TYPE" OR "CREDITTYPEID" LIKE "A1"."CREDIT_TYPE"||'%FRS')



Note
-----
   - fully remote statement
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=7)
```

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that you want what appears to be 4 Cartesian products so it seems unlikely that this query actually produces the results you want.  Asking whether a query that produces incorrect results has performance issues is kind of pointless-- why bother optimizing something before you've made it work.  It seems unlikely that you want to mix old style joins with ANSI joins-- use one or the other.  Preferably ANSI joins.  If you fix all those issues, whether you have a performance issue will depend on the query plan which you haven't shown.

Comment: its left join right, how come a cartesian product, i can include the query plan

Comment: There are no join conditions for the `cr`, `crd_typ`, `evt_typ`, or `disputes` tables.  Thus you're asking Oracle to generate a Cartesian product of those tables and the tables you've actually specified join conditions for.

Comment: I have added the query plan, but there is no cartesian product

Comment: Your query plan includes a whole lot of access and filter predicates that don't appear in your query.  So I suspect that query you posted isn't actually the query you're running.

Comment: thats right, I have given a part of the query which includes all the tables , rest is the where conditions only

Comment: Then you've eliminated all the join conditions for the majority of your tables.  The query you posted would be doing multiple Cartesian joins.  The query you actually have is not.  That makes it pretty impossible to guess at performance.  It also makes it impossible to know whether you are doing inner or outer joins, whether those outer joins make sense given the chain of tables you're joining through, etc.

Comment: Justin Cave, the original query i posted, if you see  table  b@db_link ta, and condition
where st.salestransactionseq = ta.salestransactionseq, is this doing inner join or is it still left join?

Comment: Yes, in the original query, you're doing an inner join between `st` and `ta`.  But for the majority of your tables-- cr, crd_typ, evt_typ, disputes-- there are no join conditions so you're doing Cartesian joins to all those tables.  Since your query plan doesn't show a bunch of Cartesian joins, I have to assume that you eliminated so much in putting together the query that you were posting that you've made it impossible for anyone to understand what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should we use left join keyword for all other tables after ga table or we can use as it is in the query. Is there any performance issues with this query?

LEFT OUTER JOIN, to give it its full name, is a two part thing

OUTER JOIN is a special case where "if the join fails, permit the solid side table/resultset to exist in the output and fill the partial side with NULLs"

The LEFT is a direction to the database as to which side shall be considered "solid". All the rows from the solid side are present at least once.

Absent any parentheses or sub queries driving execution direction:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON ...
```

`a` is the left; `a` is thus the solid side. All rows from `a` will be present. Rows from `b` may be present or null if the join predicates matched no rows

Once this is done this whole resultset of "a and b, nulls, warts and all" will become "the left side" for subsequent joins

```
SELECT *
FROM
  a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b
  some_kind_of JOIN c
```

Is effectively the same as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM
    a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN b
) newLeft
some_kind_of JOIN c
```

Remember, the OUTER specifier permits the join to fail and still keeps the declared solid side rows

Whether you can use INNER or LEFT/RIGHT OUTER to join `c` in depends on *what you're joining it to*

If you're joining it to, say, a column from `a` then it could be fine to use INNER or OUTER - you'd use whatever you'd use if `b` wasn't even in the picture.

- Will the join from a to c fail sometimes and you still want the rows from a? Use an OUTER.
- Will it never fail, or do you not want any rows that do fail? Use an INNER.

However, if you're joining it to a column that was provided by `b` then you probably are going to want to use some OUTER join, otherwise there will have been no point making the query do `a left outer join b` - rows from `b`b will definitely have a NULL where the join failed but you wanted to keep those ones.. If you then `INNER JOIN c` to some column from b, that was NULL because the join failed, then the row will disappear from the output. Nothing is ever equal to NULL, so the INNER JOIN to `c` on the NULL in the column from `b`. In effect the INNER JOIN undoes all that good work done keeping `a`'s data, by the OUTER join that joined `b`'s data

Doing

```
a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id
```

allows those rows from a-join-b where b.c_id is null (because the join failed) to stay in the output (because it's an outer join to C, not an inner one)..

..

Generally we inner join everything we can, then switch to left joining everything else because it makes the queries easier to follow. In that "if c is being inner joined to a" scenario we would perhaps:

```
a 
INNER JOIN c on a.c_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id
```

Rather than:

```
a 
LEFT JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id
INNER JOIN c on a.c_id = c.id
```

---

If a table is being joined to a table that was left joined, left join it too. Avoid RIGHT join because it goes against the evaluation direction of SQL and makes things harder to reason about; any time you think about using a right join, turn it around and rewrite it as a left.

Don't forget to use sub queries too. If you want every `a` joined to `b` which is joined to `c` only if both b and c sides match, it's probably clearest to:

```
a 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM b INNER JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id
) b_and_c
```

Try to see your SQL as developing some growing-wider-with-every-join resultset that, at every join, becomes the new left side

Comment: Its bit confusing for me, i have to go through it for few times to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Any bits you need clarifying just let me know